# Name conflict between member function and class name

Tags: c++, name-clash, name-conflict, name-collision

I'm writing a chess program with wxWidgets. At one point, I have a subclass of `wxGLCanvas`, and it makes use of a `Move` class I wrote. Unfortunately, it seems like there's a method `wxWindowBase::Move()`, and so all my statements of the form `list<Move> li` won't compile.

Is there any nice way to resolve this? I've tried `list< ::Move> li`, and that does fix the problem, but it's gross, and I have to make that change everywhere. Unlike with namespace conflicts, a using-declaration doesn't seem to help here.

Comment: What `using` declaration (or equivalently, `typedef`) did you try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to disambiguate a base class hidden by a method name.

```
typedef Move::Move Move_Base; // 1. the LHS of :: operator ignores functions
using typename Move::Move; // 2. non-template "typename" avoids constructor
typedef class Move Move_Base; // 3. elaborated type specifier
typedef ::Move Move_Base; // 4. namespace qualification (as mentioned)
```

(1) may not work in GCC due to a bug. (Not sure; you can try and see.)

(2) is perhaps the most elegant, but the compiler has to get some C++11 nuances right. The `typename` keyword there is illegal in C++03, but I think it's not necessary. In C++11, the syntax refers to the constructor instead of the type name unless you say `typename`.

You'll need to qualify the inherited function as `wxWindowBase::Move()`.

(3) only works when the base class is part of the current namespace, which often it shouldn't be.

(4) is a bit of a pain because a class hard-coded against its enclosing namespace needs modification if moved to another namespace. As you mentioned, a bit ugly.

Comment: No permutation of 2) seems to work, but somehow I forgot about typedefs, which will more-or-less fix my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @HenrySwanson Hmm, [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/306b81401a5b46bd) accepts the declaration, but Clang doesn't, which looks like a bug. However, GCC still [doesn't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b2cf5115e59aeac) interpret such a declaration as resolving the ambiguity, which is another bug.

Answer (score 1):

Put your code into a namespace.  Then your class will be `something::Move` and it won't conflict as easily.

Comment: That seems like the same problem though; it's just a difference of which namespace it's in. I like being able to have `using something::Move` in my .cpp files, so things like `std::list<something::Move>` become `list<Move>`, which is much more readable, IMO.

Comment: I don't understand: if your code is in `namespace something`, then you can say `list<Move>` without `using` it.

Comment: I can, but it still mistakes `Move` the class for `Move` the method.

Comment: @HenrySwanson: maybe you should just rename your class and sidestep this mess.

Comment: I could, but what else would I call a class that stores 'this is where the piece went and if it captured'? I was just hoping there was some way of making it pretty; I can live with the extra `::`.

Comment: `Action`?  I dunno, we're bike shedding now.  :)